# Android Google Maps API key and their stats not appearing

Tags: android, google-maps

I generated Maps API key for android app using [Google's manual](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey) via [this page](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup). Maps are working but in google console there are no stats. Do you now why and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: As it turned out there are no limits to show maps on Andorid.